# Keep App in Focus

Tags: wsh

I use wscript to launch an application on my machine. I then use this app for 30 seconds before I kill it. I do this using python -

```
import win32com.client
import time
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run("My App")
time.sleep(0.5)
shell.SendKeys('%f')
...
```

I was wondering if it is possible to ensure that the launched app receives the SendKeys instructions and not another app that I might accidentally give focus to under this 30 second period.

Thanks,

Barry.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

- how to guarantee a wsh script `SendKeys` event goes to a specifically targted application

### Workaround

- in lieu of a straightforward solution to targeting a specific process with `SendKeys` you can use the "wait" variant of ShellRun

### Example

- Change "Before" into "After"

#### Before

`WshShell.Run(run_name)`

#### After

`WshShell.Run(run_name,1,true)`